# Can we specify a specific user settings.xml to use via pom.xml?

Tags: java, build, maven, pom.xml

I would like to know if someone found a trick to specify a settings.xml file in a (parent) pom.xml.

The goal is to avoid every developer to have their own -possibly "customize"- version of those settings. Instead it would be set on a central location on the corporate network.

I'm aware of the "-s" that works on the command-line, but since we use Eclipse, it would be much simple to have it set in the main project pom file.

Thanks for your help,

-Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do that.

You can tell everyone to use a copy of maven in which you edit the global settings (conf/settings.xml).